# FIFO doesn't read sometimes in all processes + Process 2 dies when trying to freeze program

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix, fifo

How this program should work:
Make 3 processes, P1 is reading line from keyboard, P2 is checking if the line is looking like this - number1+number2+...+number n, P3 is giving me sum of this equation.
This works fine.

The second part is that I have to use Signals+FIFO to either stop(S1-SIGINT), freeze(S2-SIGUSR1) or resume(S3-SIGUSR2) work in this program. One signal should store the info about what signal was called in FIFO, and then using another signal(S4) tell every other process what to do.

When giving S1 to the process, it sometimes works for 1,2 or 3 processes, when sending S2 to any process, P2 dies, and only P2. I don't know why it works like that.

Yes, i have to use Signals + FIFO.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define MAX 1000

#define S1 SIGINT
#define S2 SIGUSR1
#define S3 SIGUSR2
#define S4 SIGCONT

#define SIGNAL "\033[1;33m\033[5m>> SIGNAL <<\033[0m\n"
void signal_callback(int signo);
void signal_rcv();
void signal_handling();
int read_line(char text[], int n);
struct msg_buffer { 
    long msg_type; 
    char msg_text[100]; 
} m; 

int fd;
char buf[2];
char inter_snd=0, inter_rcv=0, work = 1, quit = 0;

int main()
{
    key_t key = ftok(".", 5);
    key_t key2 = ftok(",", 4);
    int msg_id = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    int msg_id2 = msgget(key2, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    mkfifo("/tmp/fifo", 0666);
    if(msg_id == -1)
    {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(msg_id2 == -1)
    {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(fork()==0)
    {
        signal(S1, signal_callback);
        signal(S2, signal_callback);
        signal(S3, signal_callback);
        signal(S4, signal_rcv);  
        do
        {
            
            if(read_line(m.msg_text, MAX)!=EOF)
            {
                if(work)
                {  
                    m.msg_type=1;
                    int length; 
                    length = strlen(m.msg_text);
                    if(msgsnd(msg_id, &m, sizeof(m),0)==-1)
                    {
                        perror("msgsnd");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    printf("[P1]Sending message.\n");
                }
            }
        }while(1);
        exit(0);
    }
    
    if(fork()==0)
    {
        signal(S1, signal_callback);
        signal(S2, signal_callback);
        signal(S3, signal_callback);
        signal(S4, signal_rcv);
        do
        {
            if(work)
            {
                m.msg_type=1;
                if(msgrcv(msg_id, &m, sizeof(m), 1, 0)==-1)
                {
                    perror("msgsnd");
                    exit(1);
                }
                else printf("[P2]Receiving message.\n");

                int length = strlen(m.msg_text), i=0, plus=0, pass=1;
                char check[1];
                for(;i<length;i++)
                {
                    check[0]=m.msg_text[i];
                    if((i == 0 && m.msg_text[0]=='+') || (i == length-1 && m.msg_text[length-1] == '+'))
                    {
                        printf("Bad\n");
                        pass=0;
                        break;
                    }
                    if((check[0]<'0' || check[0]>'9') && check[0] != '+')
                    {
                        printf("Bad\n");
                        pass=0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(check[0] == '+')

                    {
                        if(plus==1)
                        {
                            printf("Bad\n");
                            pass=0;
                            break;
                        }
                        plus++;
                    }
                    else plus =0;
                }
                if(pass==1)
                {
                    m.msg_type=2;
                    if(msgsnd(msg_id2, &m, sizeof(m),0)==-1)
                    {
                        perror("msgsnd");
                    }
                    printf("[P2]Sending message.\n");
                }
            }
        }while(1);
        exit(0);
    }
    if(fork()==0)
    {
        signal(S1, signal_callback);
        signal(S2, signal_callback);
        signal(S3, signal_callback);
        signal(S4, signal_rcv);
        do
        {
            if(work)
            {
                m.msg_type=2;
                if(msgrcv(msg_id2, &m, sizeof(m), 2, 0)==-1)
                {
                    perror("msgsnd");
                }
                printf("[P3]Receiving message.\n");
                int count=0, i=0,length = strlen(m.msg_text), nr=0, sum=0;
                char check[1];
                int numbers[20];
                for(; i<length; i++)
                {
                    check[0]= m.msg_text[i];
                    if(check[0] == '+')
                    {
                        char number[20];
                        strncpy(number, m.msg_text+(i-count), count);
                        number[count] = '\0';
                        int a = atoi(number);
                        numbers[nr] = a;
                        nr++;
                        count =0;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                {
                char number[20];
                strncpy(number, m.msg_text+(i-count), count);
                number[count] = '\0';
                int a = atoi(number);
                numbers[nr] = a;
                nr++;
                count =0;
                }
                i=0;
                for(;i<nr; i++)
                {
                    sum += numbers[i];
                }
                printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
            }
        }while(1);
        
        exit(0);
    }
   
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Program end.\n");
    msgctl(msg_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);     
    msgctl(msg_id2, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    remove("/tmp/fifo");
}
int read_line(char text[], int n)
{
    char *ptext;
    int return_value;
    int length;
    ptext = fgets(text, n, stdin);
    if(ptext == NULL)
    {
        return_value = EOF;
    }
    else
    {
        length = strlen(text);
        if(length>0 && text[length-1]=='\n')    text[length-1]='\0';
        return_value=1;
    }    
    
    return return_value;
}
void signal_callback(int signo)
{
    //printf("%sSignal %d in PID %d\n", SIGNAL, signo, (int)getpid());
    inter_snd = signo;
    signal_handling();
}
void signal_rcv()
{
    //printf("cos");
    fd=open("/tmp/fifo", O_RDWR);
    
    if(read(fd, &inter_snd, sizeof(char)))
    {
        //printf("przeczytal");
    }
    //printf("inter_snd = %d\n", inter_snd);
    
    switch (inter_snd)
    {
    case S1:
        //printf("%d Quitting...\n", (int)getpid());
        _exit(0);
        break;
    case S2:
        //printf("%d Stopping...\n", (int)getpid());
        work = 0;
        break;
    case S3:
        //printf("%d Starting...\n", (int)getpid());
        work = 1;
        break;
    default: break;
        //printf("There's garbage in memory :/..\n");
    }

}
void signal_handling(void)
{
    if (inter_snd>0)
    {
        //printf("Signal received...\n");
        fd = open("/tmp/fifo", O_RDWR);
        write(fd, &inter_snd, sizeof(char));
        write(fd, &inter_snd, sizeof(char));
        write(fd, &inter_snd, sizeof(char));
        inter_snd = 0;
        //printf("Sending to other processes\n");
        kill(0, S4);
    }
}
```

(Used non-async functions just to let me see what is happening)

Comment: Can you use pthreads + locks? That would greatly simplify this, and remove the need for signals. Also, the sequence of events you listed does not obtain any benefit from using processes or concurrency instead of normal serial code.

Comment: @ImportAccelerate no, I have to use it like that.

Comment: I'm curious, is this a school assignment or something? Why can you not do this serially?

Comment: @ImportAccelerate project for uni :/

Comment: It seems weird that you're using a named pipe instead of an anonymous pipe.  Rather than creating the named pipe, just invoke `pipe()` before you fork.  If you're trying to send data to multiple processes, you'll want more than one pipe.

Comment: You never close the file descriptors opened in your signal handler.

Comment: @AndrewHenle tried to close them, but nothing changed.

Comment: @WilliamPursell if only I could do anonymous pipe. I can't.

Comment: You don't check for enough errors.  You have `key_t key2 = ftok(",", 4);` but most directories do not contain a file called `,` so you probably get `key2` of `-1`, which is likely to lead to problems.  You should really create three functions — for example, `child1()`, `child2()` and `child3()` — each of which does the processing for the relevant child.

Comment: The code for child 1 does not terminate when it reads EOF.  The code for child 2 and child 3 can't tell when child 1 exits due to EOF — I'm not sure how that's supposed to work.